# how to add element with multiple attribute to a specific node

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

here is my XML doc

```
<Filters>
  <Filter Name="ddd">
    <File Name="filename.xls" Location="\\path\filename.xls">
      <Sheet Name="'sheetname'">
        <field Name="Pick up point" Condition="LIKE" Value="k" />
      </Sheet>
    </File>
  </Filter>
  <Filter Name=""ccc>
    <File Name="filename.xls" Location="\\path\filename.xls">
      <Sheet Name="'sheetname'">
        <field Name="Pick up point" Condition="LIKE" Value="k" />
      </Sheet>
   </File>
 </Filter>
<Filters>
```

now what i want is to have multiple field elements but this field element comes from a loop here is how i was making it

```
xml.Add(new XElement("Filter", new XAttribute("Name", getCriteriaName),
  new XElement("File", new XAttribute("Name", getFileName), new XAttribute("Location", excelFileLocation),
  new XElement("Sheet", new XAttribute("Name", getExcelSheetName),
  new XElement("field", new XAttribute("Name", getExcelColumnName), new XAttribute("Value", getCondition))))));
xml.Save(fileLocation);
```

i changed the code like this

```
xml.Add(new XElement("Filter", new XAttribute("Name", getCriteriaName),
     new XElement("File", new XAttribute("Name", getFileName), new XAttribute("Location", excelFileLocation),
     new XElement("Sheet", new XAttribute("Name", getExcelSheetName))));
while (conditions.Rows.Count > rowCount)
{

    xml.Add(new XElement("field", new XAttribute("Name", conditions.Rows[rowCount][0]),new XAttribute("Condition", conditions.Rows[rowCount][1]), new XAttribute("Value", conditions.Rows[rowCount][2])));

    isSaved = true;
    rowCount++;
}
xml.Save(fileLocation);
```

but it is making field after the filter tag closes how can i do it in the above format

Answer (score 3):

Well yes, you're calling `xml.Add` when you actually want to call `Add` on the object representing the `Sheet` element.

I suggest you use:

```
XElement sheet = new XElement("Sheet", new XAttribute("Name", getExcelSheetName);
while (conditions.Rows.Count > rowCount)
{
    sheet.Add(new XElement("field", ...));
    isSaved = true; // Unclear what this is for...
    rowCount++;
}
xml.Add(new XElement("Filter", new XAttribute("Name", getCriteriaName),
             new XElement("File", ...),
             sheet);
```

You may well also be able to express all those `field` elements as a query:

```
XElement sheet = new XElement("Sheet", new XAttribute("Name", getExcelSheetName),
    conditions.Rows.Select(row => ...));
```